# How to bind JSON child array to Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Let´s say I have the following JSON data, which is the response data of an HTTP service call...

```
{
    [ "container" : [ 
        { 
            "category" : "default", 
            "items" : [ 
                { "name" : "item-1" }, 
                { "name" : "item-2" } 
            ]
        } ]
    ]
}
```

I want to bind the `items` array to the Kendo UI Grid, so I defined the following data source...

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://...",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                Accept: "application/json"
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: ???
    }
});
```

I´ve absolutely no clue how to define the model schema because I couldn´t find any information on that particular binding scenario in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the response, you have defined `container` as an `array` but not sure if it might repeat. As far as I understand the actual data is `items`. Correct? If so, this is the minimum DataSource definition.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url     : "http://...",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                Accept: "application/json"
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize : 10,
    schema   : {
        data: "container[0].items"
    }
});
```

**NOTE**: The response that you show doesn't look like a JSONP but a JSON. That's why I'm setting `dataType` as JSON.

Comment: Changing the dataType to JSON and using your schema definition works fine. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at the example here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.model) which has what I think you are looking for.