# Web method return JSON result in two level (In kendoUI Datasource)

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

**This the server side Code**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static object GetDevelopers()
    {
        return new DqListViewModel(DQContext.Service._IDqs_IssueRepository.SelectList().ToArray(), 10);
    }
```

**View Model**

```
public class DqListViewModel
{
    public Array Data { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public DqListViewModel(Array data, int count)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.Count = count;
    }
}
```

**This is the JSON return Value**

[image]

**why the JSON result has tow level object. I am not supposed to have "d" level?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below link. http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

This is not an issue from Knedo-ui but it is the functionality of the Asp.net

Please try with the below link, may be it will help you.
[How to bind JSON child array to Kendo grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816936/how-to-bind-json-child-array-to-kendo-grid/17818904#17818904)